# power bi DAX forward fill future dates with last value in a table in the last populated month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with 2 rows a value for Jan 2019 and Feb 2019. I am creating a bar chart that shows all 12 months in 2019. I want to drag out the last value in February and fill it into the remaining 10 months of the chart.

I am writing this measure to try and achieve this but it is returning blanks for march to dec. jan and feb seem to be correct.

```
GrossRev ACT = 

VAR

lastval = CALCULATE(sum(GrossRev ACT[ADV REVENUES EUR]), PREVIOUSMONTH(GrossRev ACT[Date]))

VAR

mdate = EOMONTH(MAX('GrossRev ACT'[Date]),0)

VAR

Alldate = EOMONTH(MAX(Dates[Date]),0)

RETURN

If (Alldate>mdate,lastval,sum(GrossRev ACT[ADV REVENUES EUR])



)
```

Any ideas would be great, basically I have some dates like in the table below were i need to populate missing future dates with the value of the latest available month. So i need the 23.587k dragged across the future months until the end of the year. The other ones are cumulative but for this one i dont want cumulative I want repeat.
[image: table fill forward future dates with last value i.e. feb 2019 duplicated in Mar to dec 2019]